# Defining \tg so it behaves exactly like \sin and \cos?

Tags: math-operators, parsing

In my country, instead of **tan**, we use **tg** (this is just one of them). I want to be able to type

```
\tg{x}
```

and possibly

```
\tgx
```

So that Latex recognizes them. I tried defining them like this:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{\text{tg}}
```

That seemed to work until I used in a block of bold text and it was bold as well, while `\sin` and `\cos` where not bold. So how can I define them correctly?

**Edit:**

I use this new operator in math blocks, like

```
The use of $ \tg{x} $
```

Or even in `\subsection` (which has a bold formatting in my document):

```
\subsection{The use od $ \tg{x} $}
```

Comment: don't use `\text` (it will use the right \mathrm font automatically)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle then what?

Comment: then it'll work as you intended, just like `\sin`  so `\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}`

Comment: +1 for using `tg`. As you may know, we have been for years in a bad period in France, and especially pessimistic people are characterized as "declinologists", of whom I am probably a representant. What's the relation? the fact that the French more and more use `tan` for no other reason that it is how it appears on the pocket calculators. Long live the `tg` of the bygone past!

Comment: @jfbu I suppose you've gone off on a tangent? :)

Comment: According to Cajori, the abbreviation “tan” was used by Finck in 1583; Euler used “tang”, but sometimes “tg”. In the 18th century, “tang” and “tan” were probably the most used abbreviations. A table in the book by Cajori seems to show that “tg” is more German than French; for instance, Legendre and Cauchy used “tang”.

Comment: @ArunDebray +1 :)

Comment: @egreg here in the material world, people are afraid of me, and anyhow I never leave them finish when they try to argue like you ;-) I will retain only that Euler used "tg" ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All you need to do is write `\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}`; this defines the command `\tg` to use the normal math font. Then, you can define `\tgx` to just be `\tg x`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\newcommand{\tgx}{\tg x}
\begin{document}
In a paragraph of normal text, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tg x$, and $\tgx$.

\textbf{
In a paragraph of bold text, $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tg x$, and $\tgx$.
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a math operator, you should do so without specifying it as being formatted as `\text`. There is no mention of this requirement in the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **5.1 Defining new operator names**):

> To define a math function `\xxx` to work like `\sin`, you write
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathOperator{\xxx}{xxx}
> ```
>
> whereupon ensuing uses of `\xxx` will produce `xxx` in the proper font and automatically add proper spacing on either side when necessary, ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}

\begin{document}

$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

$\tg^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

{\bfseries $\tg^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are typing in Spanish, load `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and you will have it available.

Comment: It's Romanian actually :)

Comment: Argh, I didn't know it was used elsewhere.

Comment: it used to be in use in France, but sadly we are not as robust as the Romanians !

Comment: @Manuel also in Russia and most other post-USSR countries.